# Loading a tensorflow 2.7.0 model with tensorflow 2.12.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to load a model previously saved using tensorflow 2.7.0 with tensorflow 2.12.0 but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: duplicate parameter name: 'training'
```

The line where the error occurs is:

tf.saved_model.load(str(model_path))

Everything worked good with version 2.7.0. What seems to be the problem? What has changed in the newer version of tensorflow and how can I fix this? If it is not possible to load older model with the newer version can I somehow save the weights from the old model to load them in a model created with 2.12.0 (after initializing the same model in the newer version)?

I tried to play with the tags and options in tf.saved_model.load but it didn't work and I have no idea what I was doing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please remove the 'str' typecast while loading the model as above `tf.saved_model.load(model_path)` and try again. As you mentioned that you have used tensorflow 2.7 while saving your model, you probably have used tf.keras API. So, you can try using  `tf.keras.models.load_model("path to model")` to load the saved model file.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error with both TensorFlow 2.12 and 2.11, where my SavedModel was saved with TensorFlow 2.4.

I tried loading the model with TensorFlow 2.10 (which works) and then saving it again and trying to load with 2.11/2.12, but that gave the same error.

For me the solution was to save the model in H5 format or the new ".keras" format (I'm not sure if this is available in 2.7, but it is available in 2.10 for sure) and then load the model as usual in 2.11/2.12.